# working in local host but error in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone explain why my rails app is working locally but not in heroku ?

This is a journal app where you can create a category and add task under it . When I create a category it is successful but when Im adding task im getting error

[1]: https://rocky-waters-91075.herokuapp.com/ This is my link to  heroku .

I check the heroku logs and getting this  NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #<Task id: nil, taskname: "dffgdfg", tasktime: "dfgdfg", taskbody: "fdfdf", category_id: 5, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Why the user_id is not showing here in params where in local it added the user_id in Task and works fine .

this is my task controller

```
 def create

 @categories = current_user.categories.find(params[:category_id])
 @category = current_user.categories.find(params[:category_id])
 @task = @category.tasks.build(task_params)
 @task.user_id = current_user.id

  if @task.save
   
    redirect_to categories_path
  else
    render :new
  end

 end
```

This works fine locally , If i check the params it has category id and user_id .

I tried to remove the  @task.user_id = current_user.id since it says that this @task.user_id is undefined but it gives me error in heroku , User must exist .

This is my User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
     has_many :categories
    has_many :tasks
 end
```

This is my task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category

validates :taskname,presence:true,uniqueness:true,length:{minimum:5}
validates :taskbody,presence:true,uniqueness:true,length:{minimum:5}


end
```

This is my Task migration file

```
  class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
  create_table :tasks do |t|
  t.string :taskname
  t.string :tasktime
  t.text :taskbody
 
  t.references :category, null: false , foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
 end
 end
 end
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: From your migration file I can tell there is no `user_id` column in the task table. Does it run locally because you have another migratio file maybe that you haven't run on heroku yet?

Comment: owww..  so i need to add user_id column in my task migration file ? thats the migration file I use locally .

Comment: I created a migration file to add user_id column in my task but it says it already exist . I also check Task.new in console and it shows there the user_id column.

Comment: Seems like you do have another migration file - check in the `db/migrate` folder... or try to just migrate again on heroku with `heroku run rails db: migrate`